# Send $_POST data to custom Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, post, plugins

I have a custom Wordpress plugin that handles many things including download pages for my products.  The links are not the path to the actual PHP page to my plugin.  For example...

```
http://myurl.com/download/product
```

But the path to my plugin that actually handles the download function is this path:

```
http://myurl.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php
```

I have built an app that uses these download links to grant a user the ability to download a product after purchase.  But now I need to send extra data along with the url.  How can I send some additional $_POST data when the users click on the download link.  I have tried

```
http://myurl.com/download/product?id=2345&user=tom
```

But when I try to echo out the variables in myplugin.php I get nothing.

```
echo $_GET['id'];

echo $_GET['user'];
```

I have also tried to use a form and send hidden inputs but still the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure no redirection is active?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump() the $_REQUEST array ?

Comment: "download" is a Wordpress page that has a shortcode connecting to the download function in 'myplugin.php'

Comment: Yes I have tried to var_dump the $_REQUEST array and it is empty

Comment: How do you bind the URL with the actual php file that processes the request? It looks like your query string is missing in this redirection...

Comment: If you only want to add these two new parameters, you can use the function wp_get_current_user() to be sure that the $_GET is not modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shortcode (maybe empty that does nothing) and put it on some page you created from WordPress.
Then, form action will be the URL to new page where you send data you need to send and method will be post.
You can handle the data you sent in new shortcode function in your plugin using $_POST['data']

This might help you as an alternative solution.